# How to attach Document to Content Approval Workflow of SharePoint 2010

Tags: workflow

I need to attach a document to Content Approval Workflow of SharePoint 2010?

Can someone guide me to the process?

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Do you mean you want to start an Approval Workflow on a document?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Content Approval WF. Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set up Content Approval for the entire document library. Here are the steps:

1. Library Settings > **Versioning Settings**
2. Content Approval: **Require content approval for submitted items? Yes**
3. Document Version History: **Create major and minor (draft versions)**
4. Draft Item Security: **Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)**

This will cause the document versions to be draft versions until the user chooses `Publish a major version`. That's when the approver can approve the document and it becomes the new version.

Here are the steps to use a workflow for content approval:

1. Select **Add a workflow** from the ribbon
2. Select workflow template: **Publishing Approval**
3. Check the box: **Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item**
4. Click Next and set up the notification information
5. Check the box for Enable Content Approval: **Update the approval status after the workflow is completed**

Note: if you do not see the Publishing Approval workflow template, the site collection administrator needs to enable the Publishing Approval Workflow feaure:

Site Actions > Site Settings > Site Collection features > Activate the Publishing Approval Workflow feature